# Android vs iOS development

Tags: android, ios, xcode, development-environment

I have just finished learning application development on android platform, as In matter of language it was easier to understand. However the convention drove me crazy yet simple enough to understand. Now the dillema is I am about to jump in iOS development. Language part wont be hard to understand but I am bit worried about design pattern or use of Xcode.

What challenges I might face which differentiate these two develoment enviroment? And which one is easier to deal with and more productive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the "Java" section in [this post](http://robnapier.net/blog/learning-cocoa-2-467). Ease and productivity are in the eye of the beholder. Many find Objective C to be incredibly natural and beautiful. Others find it bizarre and frustrating. If you're willing to embrace the iOS way of doing things, you can pick it up very fast. If you fight it and try to keep coding in Java ways (or C way, or C++ ways), then it will be very challenging. The trick is to really work through the tutorials and not just try to figure out "how do I do X that I'm used to doing?" Often the answer is "you don't do X. X happens automatically when you do Y." But the place to start is working through some tutorials.

The Apple documentation is mostly excellent. You should spend time reading through the Programming Guides. Don't just jump to the References. You'll be very confused.

Comment: Great answer!  I have used both Xcode and Eclipse.  Xcode wins for me hands down as the better IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Now i can give you some facts about both that i find really important for clearing your dilemna :
1. Ios development is really costly as it requires a mac as well a hardware device such as iphone to stimulate which costs much more than other phones that you might already know by yourself
2.Android developer have to pay 25$ to become android developer while for Ios it take 100$ per year and your subscription dies after that so yeah again Ios costs much more.
3.Now, swift is used in case of Objective C which is incredibly easy,efficient and I ensure you will fall in love with it(according to me its easier than java itself).
4.Lastly,I myself have worked with the android studio and believe me, Xcode is now easier than android studio(with bugs fixed).

So,the zest is Ios development is costly but its worth learning it and now apple shifting to the new Swift, its super easy now and for the layout stuff don't worry, with time you will get a hang for it

Answer (score -1):

Android and iOS operating system are best at its place. Both are doing good, but it is obvious that one OS can have any feature as pro while other can have it as a cons.

Well, this is my personal opinion that i will choose Android over iPhone for below reasons.

Obviously the first is Price. You can afford a pretty good Android Smartphone with awesome hardware configuration in same or cheap than the price of the iPhone.
Customization: You can customize the way you want like install other OS like Cyanogen and a lot custom Android OS is available over internet (Flexible OS). iPhone is limited to customization. Though jailbreak option is available, but who wants to knowingly spoil that handsome price iPhone. Tons of customized screen launcher available in Android.
Battery: Early battery drain is always the problem in iPhone. Well, battery saving gets better in Android with the Doze feature introduced in Marshmallow. And the good part is, most Android phone’s battery are replaceable and it is pretty easy stuff as compare to iPhone.
Multi-tasking support with multi-window feature and flexible widget in Android.
More free apps as compare to iOS
Custom ROMs. Android gives full control (root) over your phone as compare to iPhone
Memory: In iPhone memory comes at huge cost and no expandable memory as compare to Android. Android supports expandable memory and it does not get that pricey with the increase in the in-built memory
Developer: For those who are willing to develop Application in Android can get the huge community support and can build apps on the affordable hardware rather than iOS. iOS hardware comes at handsome cost as compare the Android.
Well, above are the few points that makes me feel Android is better than iPhone. And no offense to the iPhone users. iPhone is best at its place.

Ref : [enter link description here](https://www.quora.com/Android-operating-system-Is-iOS-better-than-Android-and-Windows-Phone)